# Apache log filled with Proxy errors from attacking ip's

Tags: firewall, proxy, apache-2.4

I have these errors in Apache log...

```
proxy:error] [pid 13317] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 210.86.231.64:80 (*) failed
[proxy_http:error] [pid 13317] [client 5.39.116.17:56290] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: simsodep.com
```

This goes on, repeated, ad infinitum. I forward proxy from Apache to JBoss.

In the :80 config...

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^ApacheBench/2.3" bad_bot
<Proxy https://exampledev.com/*>
    Require all denied
    Deny from env=bad_bot
    Require ip 12.34.56.78
    Require host exampledev.com
</Proxy>
Redirect permanent / https://exampledev.com
```

And in the :443 config...

```
<Proxy https://exampledev.com/*>
    Require all denied
    Deny from env=bad_bot
    Require host exampledev.com
    Require ip 12.34.56.78
</Proxy>
```

In my firewall, through ufw, I have...

```
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] Anywhere                   DENY IN     210.86.231.64
[ 5] Anywhere                   DENY IN     5.39.116.17
[ 6] 22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 7] 443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 8] 80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Why is my Apache 2.4 log file being filled with gigs from these proxy errors? What am I missing?

Comment: In your firewall, put the deny rules first and then the allowed ones, then see again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your firewall rules order.

The order of firewall rules are very important as they are processed/matched in order. So, if there is an allow rule matched first, then the deny rule that comes later wont work as expected.

Change the rules so that the deny rules are on top or matched first before all other accept rules. They should look like this:

```
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Anywhere                   DENY IN     210.86.231.64
[ 2] Anywhere                   DENY IN     5.39.116.17
[ 3] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 7] 443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 8] 80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Well, of course this is not the optimal way of banning ip one at a time. Securing your Web server is a broader issue and there are many materials available online.

As for firewall, you can try  fail2ban:

[How To Protect an Apache Server with Fail2Ban on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-apache-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: This worked. Of course, I had to edit the lib/ufw/user6.rules directly. However, I'm still hammered by every other attacker in the world, giving me endless proxy:error's in the log.

Comment: Well, if this answer has worked, then consider accepting it as an answer. Securing your server is a broader issue and there are many materials available online. As for firewall, you can try fail2ban:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-apache-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Accepted. Appreciate it! ...and for the further advice. I'd vote it up, if i could.